# Filtering out highest integer from an array of links

Tags: php, arrays, integer, hyperlink

But of a confusing title so let me explain. I have an array of links like this:

```
http://somesite.com/videoplayback?ip=81.0.0.0&sparams=id,expire,ip,ipbits,itag,algorithm,burst,factor&fexp=905602&algorithm=throttle-factor&itag=34&ipbits=8&burst=40&sver=3&expire=1285056000&key=yt1&signature=690F9475D5288F3129F84364427B2B490B6ACE59.45C8F83DEE3DD361855B12AE538EA6349FF8EF9B&factor=1.25&id=d50e6528eb51ad54,18

http://somesite.com/videoplayback?ip=81.0.0.0&sparams=id,expire,ip,ipbits,itag,algorithm,burst,factor&fexp=905602&algorithm=throttle-factor&itag=18&ipbits=8&burst=40&sver=3&expire=1285056000&key=yt1&signature=A68EAA3F7A2ECA2BB2BD6C35BF443C03E4BB1172.AD2FF9FDAF046B23F789FE1A7F7882DF9A355DE4&factor=1.25&id=d50e6528eb51ad54,5

http://somesite.com/videoplayback?ip=81.0.0.0&sparams=id,expire,ip,ipbits,itag,algorithm,burst,factor&fexp=905602&algorithm=throttle-factor&itag=5&ipbits=8&burst=40&sver=3&expire=1285056000&key=yt1&signature=ABC8ACF6899C46CC992ECB5F6A6FD7E66383EA3D.0C8B707083203DC1153FB26586A94BFAC64D176B&factor=1.25&id=d50e6528eb51ad54
```

If you look at the very end of those URL's, they have extensions like `,18`, `,5` and there is one last link with no extension like this at all.

Now, I need to use the link that has the highest number on the end as possible later in my code. In this example I need to filter out the very first link, because it has the highest integer on the end (`18`).

I would use a series of `if()` blocks, but in this case the integers on the end can change so that's not a good solution.

So I basically need to go through my array, check which link has the highest integer at the end (note that it is only 2 digits in length) and then store it in another variable.

Can anyone provide some sample/psudo code on how to effectively do this?

Cheers.

Comment: Damn, if it wasn't for the 'can have nothing', we could employ an überevil `max(array_map('intval',array_map('strrev',array_map('intval',array_map('strrev',$array)))));`

Comment: Haha, that's one hell of a line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work even if there are commas in other places in the URL:

```
$links = array("http://somesite.com/videoplayback?ip=81.0.0.0&sparams=id,expire,ip,ipbits,itag,algorithm,burst,factor&fexp=905602&algorithm=throttle-factor&itag=34&ipbits=8&burst=40&sver=3&expire=1285056000&key=yt1&signature=690F9475D5288F3129F84364427B2B490B6ACE59.45C8F83DEE3DD361855B12AE538EA6349FF8EF9B&factor=1.25&id=d50e6528eb51ad54,18", "http://somesite.com/videoplayback?ip=81.0.0.0&sparams=id,expire,ip,ipbits,itag,algorithm,burst,factor&fexp=905602&algorithm=throttle-factor&itag=18&ipbits=8&burst=40&sver=3&expire=1285056000&key=yt1&signature=A68EAA3F7A2ECA2BB2BD6C35BF443C03E4BB1172.AD2FF9FDAF046B23F789FE1A7F7882DF9A355DE4&factor=1.25&id=d50e6528eb51ad54,5", "http://somesite.com/videoplayback?ip=81.0.0.0&sparams=id,expire,ip,ipbits,itag,algorithm,burst,factor&fexp=905602&algorithm=throttle-factor&itag=5&ipbits=8&burst=40&sver=3&expire=1285056000&key=yt1&signature=ABC8ACF6899C46CC992ECB5F6A6FD7E66383EA3D.0C8B707083203DC1153FB26586A94BFAC64D176B&factor=1.25&id=d50e6528eb51ad54");

$max = 0;
$highestLink = "";
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $data = explode(",", strrev($link));
    $val = strrev($data[0]);
    if (is_numeric($val)) {
        $val = (int) $val;
        if ($val > $max) {
            $max = $val;
            $highestLink = $link;
        }
    }
}

echo $max;
```

Comment: That doesn't put anything in `$highestLink`, I'll look through it in a sec :) Thanks. PS: What does the `!!` in the `if()` statement mean? If it's `NOT NOT` isn't it redundant? Thanks.

Comment: It does through these lines: `if ($val > $max) { ... $highestLink = $link;` Although I changed my code (see the edits) I was using `!!` incorrectly. I meant to say `strstr(",", $line) === false` instead. You can't just use `==` because if `,` is found at position 0, `0 == false` so the condition would be triggered incorrectly. `===` ensures the value is `false` and not `0`.

Answer (score 0):

For the obfuscation award:

```
array_multisort(
    array_map('intval',preg_replace('/^.*?(,([0-9]+))?$/','$2',$array)),
    $array);
echo end($array);
```

Comment: Yes, but multisort is by reference, so `max(boolean true)` => `true` would fail. And the OP doesn't want `max`, he wants _'the url with specific condition max'_